# Dynamically Generated Checkboxes unable to check

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to check/uncheck check boxes which were generated dynamically. But i am not able to do so.
What i am trying to do is - say, i have 5 check boxes, on clicking 5th check box, previous 4 should also get checked.
Following is the code :

```
function checkImages(id) {
    if ($('#' + id).is(":checked")) {
        for (i = parseInt(id) ; i >= 0; i--) {          
            $("#" + id).attr("checked", true);
        }
    } else {
        $(".selectedImages").prop("checked", false);
    }
}
```

HTML :

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.ImageList.Count; i++)
{
    <div id="id @i" style=" margin:10px; float:left; height:100px; overflow:hidden; width:100px;">
        <input type="checkbox" id=@i name="selectedImages" value="Weekly" onclick="checkImages(id);">
    </div>
}
```

Here you see id="2" is checked but id="1" doesn't have any checked attribute

[image: Here you see id="2" is checked but id="1" doesn't have any checked attribute]

Comment: Why do you `attr(.., true)` but `prop(.., false)`?

Comment: Maybe: `onclick="checkImages(@id)"`?    In your checkImages, function, add:  `alert(id)` to see what you're being passed.

Comment: I did first but it didn't work , then i used attr..It doesn't work either.

Comment: I am getting id number in the alert. I have checked that adding alert.

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous issues with your code, the main one:

```
$("#" + id).attr("checked", true);
```

should be

```
$("#" + i).prop("checked", true);
```

and the clear code:

```
$(".selectedImages").prop("checked", false);
```

selects by class, but your elements have `name=selectedImages` so should be:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="@i" class="selectedImages" ...
```

Finally, your loop goes to 0, but the first element is 1 (a minor issue).

Assuming your `onclick=` code is passing the correct value, here's updated code

Sample HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" id="1" class="selectedImages" value="Weekly" onclick="checkImages('1');">
<input type="checkbox" id="2" class="selectedImages" value="Weekly" onclick="checkImages('2');">
<input type="checkbox" id="3" class="selectedImages" value="Weekly" onclick="checkImages('3');">
```

jquery:

```
function checkImages(id) {
    if ($('#' + id).is(":checked")) {
        for (i = parseInt(id) ; i >= 1; i--) {          
            $("#" + i).prop("checked", true);
        }
    } else {
        $(".selectedImages").prop("checked", false);
    }   
}
```

Example codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BKoGaq

---

However, it would be remiss of me to not mention that you shouldn't be using numeric IDs like this - instead use `data-` attributes, eg:

html:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-id="1" class="selectedImages" value="Weekly" onclick="checkImages(this);">
<input type="checkbox" data-id="2" class="selectedImages" value="Weekly" onclick="checkImages(this);">
<input type="checkbox" data-id="3" class="selectedImages" value="Weekly" onclick="checkImages(this);">
```

jquery

```
function checkImages(el) {
   id = $(el).data("id");
   console.log(id)
   if ($(el).is(":checked")) {
        for (i = parseInt(id) ; i >= 1; i--) {          
            $(".selectedImages[data-id='" + i + "']").prop("checked", true);
        }
    } else {
        $(".selectedImages").prop("checked", false);
    }   
}
```

and you could also use jquery event handler rather than "onclick".